res.clearCookie method is not clearing cookies on the browser dev tools
I'm trying to make a Sign Out function on React-Express Web App. But it doesn't clear my cookie.
Code when set the cookie
res.cookie('!', t, {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: "strict",
    priority: "high"
})
res.status(200).json()

Code to removing the cookie
const SignOut = (_: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.clearCookie('!')
    res.status(200).json()
}
export default SignOut

Route
import RegCon from '../controllers/Register'
import LogCon from '../controllers/Login'
import OutCon from '../controllers/SignOut'

const router = express.Router({
    caseSensitive: true,
    strict: true
})
router.post('/API/register', RegCon)
router.post('/API/login', LogCon)
router.delete('/API/signout', OutCon)

React SignOut handler
const handleSignOut = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/API/signout')
            // location.href = '/'
        } catch (err) {
            const XR = err as AxiosError
            alert(XR.response!.statusText)
        }
    }

The things that makes me more even confuse is its not fall into the catch, its actually succeeded but it doesn't clear my cookie on here
Anybody could explain why?

You can just test that your res.clearCookie(...) is working or not by putting res.clearCookie just below the res.cookie(...) just for testing purpose. If it clears the cookie successfully then issue might be in your signout method. Also, Double-check your  res.clearCookie(...) attributes (options) with res.cookie(...). Also you can verify that cookie cleared or not on browser by refreshing once.

Your axios.delete uses an absolute URL, is the HTML page not from the same origin (http://localhost:3001)?

As per express documnetation here, you need to pass the options parameter which should be identical to the one that you define when you set the cookie with the exception of expires and maxAge.
So, your sign out function should look something like this:
const SignOut = (_: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.clearCookie('!', {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      sameSite: "strict",
      priority: "high",
      path: '/' // add this path when setting the cookie as well
    });
    res.status(200).json()
}


it still same, whether I add the path or not, it doesnt clear my cookie.

It's not just the path. you need the other parameters as well

What I meant is I did like u wrote, still same.

Duplicate of : res.clearCookie is not clearing cookies despite matching options
You are not sending back the request, so the res object here is stuck inside the SignOut function.
You need to return it so it is sending the response with the cleared cookies
const SignOut = (_: Request, res: Response): Response=> ({
    res.clearCookie('!')
    return res.status(200).json()
})

export default SignOut


If I giving a return, there's another Typescript Error warning on my route

Without sharing the TypeScript error, i can't really help.
I think, though, that this is somehow unrelated. From what i assume, you're missing to provide the ReturnType of SignOut function, which is a different problem than the other one. If you're not matching the types of what you are returning, TypeScript will throw an error. I have edited my answer accordingly

Well acutally its same tho but plus a TS warning

Have you considered using .send(), as res.status(200).json().send() ?
